# Use iphone bluetooth to control a robot

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm building a robot to serve drinks and cool stuff like that. I'd like to build an iOS app to control it. That way I can save money on building a remote when I start mass producing it.

I've built iOS apps in the past but never one that interacted with something outside of the phone.

I've found a lot of outdated posts saying that you need to have a "made for iphone" device to communicate with the device via Bluetooth and that wifi is the better option. The most up to date article I've found is regarding iOS 5.

Is that still the case or has it been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS now supports Bluetooth 4.0. You would probably be well served to checkout the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257%20%22Core%20Bluetooth%20Programming%20Guide).

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff pointed out, CoreBluetooth (also known as Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth 4.0) is now a public framework for iOS that let you interact with the next generation of Bluetooth devices.  The advantages for this is that you don't need a "Made For iPhone License" and these modules can last for months to years depending on your needs.  The disadvantage is that it doesn't/can't do some of the things that Bluetooth 3 can do, such as transmit music wirelessly, but that shouldn't matter for simply sending commands to a robot.  I won't bother you with all the details at this point (since it seems like you're still looking at this conceptually) but you would simply need to have a Bluetooth module in your robot that the phone could connect to, and the phone can then write data that could be perceived as commands.